# Problems with integrating a (step) probability density function

Tags: probability, integration, probability-distributions

I've been sitting a embarrassing amount of time over this problem:

I am given a probability density function f(x) like this:

```
y= 1/6  when x between [-2,-1]
y= 2/6 when x between [-1,1]
y= 1/6  when x between [1,2]
y= 0 else
```

My task is to find out how probable it is to get an result between **0.5 and 1.5**

My solution for this is:

$$
\int_{0.5}^1\;\frac26\;dx\;+\;\int_1^{1.5}\;\frac16\;dx\;=\;\frac3{12}
$$

My professor's solution is **1/3**, so I am probably doing something wrong. I have done the calculation several times so I hope it's not just that. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: Your answer is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer seems to be correct as $\int_{0.5}^1 \frac{2}{6} dx = 0.5 * \frac{2}{6} = \frac{1}{6}$ and $\int_1^{1.5} \frac{1}{6} dx = 0.5 \frac{1}{6} = \frac{1}{12}$

And the sum of the two is obviously $\frac{3}{12} = \frac{1}{4}$.

Comment: Thank you! I was beginning to go crazy...